# After save empty cache of referenced node

Tags: views, 8, caching

I have two content types. For clearer question I will work with the content types *event* and *location*.

From my *location* content type I can reference to and *event*.

Then on the *event* page I show the *location* that is connected to this *event*. I do this by creating a Views Block. This views block is showing content of the type *location* with a contextual filter to only show content with the *Content ID from url*.

This works fine. But there are events that don't have a *location*. On these events page I have a button saying *add location*. I do this with the following [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{% if drupal_view_result('view-name', 'location-block') is empty %}
    <a href="/node/add/location">Add location</a>
{% else %}
    {{ drupal_view('view-name', 'location-block') }}
{% endif %}
```

This also works. But when I am on a *event* page and click the *add location* button I can add the location. When I go back to the same *event page* I was before I still see the *add location* button. Because the page is cached.

Is there a way to empty the cache of this *event* page after saving the *location* that is refering to the *event*? Or is there a other way to deal with this?

I tried if the problem was in the views cache but it wasn't turning it off for the block or removing only the views cache didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you might need some extra cache tags or cache contexts for nodes in this case.

Comment: It sure does but I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Better place the View in a block and put the button in the no results area.

Comment: @4k4 this would have been a nice option but I need the nid of the events page I am looking at so to be precise the link should be something like: `<a href="/node/add/location?nid={{nid}}">Add location</a>` I couldn't find a way to do this with Views.

Comment: @Joost, for the current node id try `[current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]` in a Views text area, see https://www.drupal.org/node/1360922

Comment: @4k4 thanks, it works like a charme without writing any custom caching module.

Answer (score 1):

You may specify any cache meta data directly in your Twig template. I suppose 'node_list' cache tag can help in this case.

```
{{ {'#cache': {'tags': ['node_list']}} }}
```

Another approach could be configuring views 'No results behavior' to show that link.

Comment: Did you test this? I don't see any document say that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating a reference to a location node, you'll know its node id upon saving the event.

At that point, you need to call `\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags([$nid])`
 where `$nid` is the node id of the location.

There are many possibilities where this could be invoked, for example, in `hook_entity_presave()`